# Riemann integrable function not of the following form

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Does there exist a Riemann integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not of the form:

$$f(x)=\phi(x)+\psi(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 1_{I_n}(x)$$

where $\phi$ is continuous, $\psi$ is zero almost everywhere, $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$, $1_{A}$ is the indicator function of $A$, and $I_i$ are disjoint intervals?

Comment: Throwing $\psi$ into the mix creates a bit of a weird issue with this formulation because not every function of your form is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Can you give an example? The reason I have it in there is to deal with functions like Thomae's function.

Comment: $1_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$ is not Riemann integrable, but it is of your form.

Comment: Good point, I should have noticed that. I understand how that is weird, but it is the converse to my question. I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: It is indeed the converse to your question, but that snag being there makes the process of imagining counterexamples a bit more difficult. Anyway, maybe you can think about Volterra's function or similar (functions which have many "essential" discontinuities rather than jumps (easily handled by your indicators) or removables (easily handled by your $\psi$)).

Comment: Take an increasing saltus function, say with jumps at every rational.  Your formulation will not handle jumps that are dense.

Comment: That answer intuitively makes sense, but, when I have more time, I'll go through it rigorously. Thanks!